# Issue with as.Date function not formatting Date in a dataset correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with the dataset below, that I would like to graph using ggplot2. However, calling ggplot2 on the data yields a bizzare graph, which could be a result of the date being misformatted. dput() shows:

```
    structure(list(date = structure(c(18283, 18284, 18285, 18288, 
    18289, 18290, 18291, 18292, 18295, 18296, 18297, 18298, 18299, 
    18302, 18303, 18304, 18305, 18306, 18309, 18310, 18311, 18312, 
    18313, 18316, 18317, 18318, 18319, 18320, 18323, 18324, 18325, 
    18326, 18327, 18330, 18331, 18332, 18333, 18334, 18337, 18338, 
    18339, 18340, 18341, 18344, 18345, 18346, 18347, 18348, 18351, 
    18352, 18353, 18354, 18355, 18358, 18359, 18360, 18361, 18362, 
    18365, 18366, 18367, 18368, 18369, 18372, 18373, 18374, 18375, 
    18376, 18379, 18380, 18381), class = "Date"), oil_price = c("56.76", 
    "55.51", "54.09", "53.09", "53.33", "53.29", "52.19", "51.58", 
    "50.06", "49.59", "50.87", "50.94", "50.34", "49.59", "50.0", 
    "51.13", "51.41", "52.03", ".", "52.1", "53.31", "53.77", "53.36", 
    "51.36", "49.78", "48.67", "47.17", "44.83", "46.78", "47.27", 
    "46.78", "45.9", "41.14", "31.05", "34.47", "33.13", "31.56", 
    "31.72", "28.96", "26.96", "20.48", "25.09", "19.48", "23.33", 
    "21.03", "20.75", "16.6", "15.48", "14.1", "20.51", "20.28", 
    "25.18", "28.36", "26.21", "23.54", "24.97", "22.9", ".", "22.36", 
    "20.15", "19.96", "19.82", "18.31", "-36.98", "8.91", "13.64", 
    "15.06", "15.99", "12.17", "12.4", "15.04")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -71L), class = "data.frame")
```

str():

```
'data.frame':   71 obs. of  2 variables:
    $ date     : Date, format: "2020-01-22" "2020-01-23" "2020-01-24" "2020- 
    01-27" ...
    $ oil_price: chr  "56.76" "55.51" "54.09" "53.09" ...
```

[bizzare ggplot graph for corresponding data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2chm.png)

To generate the graph I used:

```
g2 <- ggplot(data = wti,  mapping = aes(x = date, y = oil_price)) +
  geom_line() +
   labs(title = "Daily Oil Prices of Q1 2020",
   x = "Date",
   y = "Oil Prices")
```

I had a similar issue with another dataset+graph where reformatting the date in the set using the command:

```
file_name$date <- as.Date(file_name$date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

remedied the issue with the graph. However, when I used the same command on this set I had no luck, and was still stuck with a strange graph.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to fix the format of the data to the correct format, thank you!

Comment: please include your data as text (using `dput()`) and not as an image. It aslso sounds like the issue is with the `as.Date` function, not ggplot so your title is a little misleading. You aremore likely to get help with a better question

Comment: We don't know enough about your data or how you are generating the plot, so it's weak. However, it looks like your "Daily Cases" variable is categorical (string/factor) and not numeric.

Comment: You need to explore your data carefully. A plot is often a good start. The result indicates that the y-axis variable is not numeric. So go back to the data and investigate. Look at the `class` of "Daily cases". Did you look at the output of `str`? These are a must! __Always__ check the data after you import it into R. Always.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post for better accuracy. And to add, I attained this data from FRED, and fairly new to R, so I am unfamiliar with how the data should be tuned before used in R.

Comment: You have your date variable on your x-axis---which looks fine. The problem is the y-axis! Your `oil_price` is `character` (string) class-not numeric (notice the quotes around the numbers). Convert it to numeric with `file_name$oil_price <- as.numeric(file_name$oil_price)` and everything should be fine.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you that fixed the issue! Side note: I'm glad I didn't capitalize ggplot2 or tag RStudio in this post!

Comment: If you had, you would have also gotten some friendly edits ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have your date variable on your x-axis---which looks fine. The problem is the y-axis! Your `oil_price` is `character` (string) `class`, not numeric (notice the quotes around the numbers, and the "chr" abbreviation in the `str()` output). Convert it to numeric with `file_name$oil_price <- as.numeric(file_name$oil_price)` and everything should be fine.

Note that, if the column had been `factor` class you would also have the same problem, but to convert `factor` to `numeric` you should go via `character`: `file_name$numeric_column <- as.numeric(as.character(file_name$factor_column))`